# Handling Complex Rules in GUI applications (C++ or C#)

Tags: c++, user-interface, mfc, logic

Im working on a dialog box in which several rules must be satisfied before the OK button is enabled.

Currently any action on the page such as entering data or selecting an item from a drop down list (amongst other things) calls a single function called ProcessEvent() - this function handles all logic and either enables or disables the OK button.

My problem is I finding it difficult making the rules concise and understandable.

Some of the rules can be negated by another action on the dialog and I have now ended up with if else statements all over the place or which are difficult to read and follow & extend.

The code below  is a simplification of the problem but demonstrates it well. How do I handle this problem better (If its Possible)

```
bool CWorkstation::ProcessEvent(void)
    {   
        UpdateData();

        CharCount = GetDlgItemInt(IDC_CharCount, NULL, FALSE); //get latest

        if ( IsDlgButtonChecked(IDC_USEDBNAME))
            {   
                if (!IsDlgButtonChecked(IDC_MAXDBNAME))
                    {
                        EnableNext(TRUE);
                    }
            }

        if (IsDlgButtonChecked(IDC_MAXDBNAME) && CharCount)
            {                   
                if (IsDlgButtonChecked(IDC_USEXMLNAME))
                    {
                        if ( PrefixName.IsEmpty() ) 
                            {
                                EnableNext(FALSE);
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                EnableNext(TRUE);
                            }
            }



            }   


        if (IsDlgButtonChecked(IDC_USEXMLNAME) && PrefixName.GetLength() > 1)
            {
                EnableNext(TRUE);
            }



        if  ( IsDlgButtonChecked(IDC_WSAUTONAME) || IsDlgButtonChecked(IDC_RENAMEIFDUP))
            {

            // TRACE("IDC_WSAUTONAME is Checked\n");

            if ( IsDlgButtonChecked(IDC_USEXMLNAME) && PrefixName.GetLength() > 1 ) 

                {   


                if ( IsDlgButtonChecked(IDC_IDC_USESHORTNAME) ) 

                    {

                    EnableNext(TRUE);
                    }

                else if ( IsDlgButtonChecked(IDC_USELONGNAME) )

                    {

                    EnableNext(TRUE);

                    }

                else

                    {
                    EnableNext(FALSE);
                    }



                }


            if ( !IsDlgButtonChecked(IDC_USEPREFIX) )

                {


                if ( IsDlgButtonChecked(IDC_IDC_USESHORTNAME) ||  IsDlgButtonChecked(IDC_USELONGNAME) )

                    {
                    EnableNext(TRUE);
                    }

                }


            return false;


            }

        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would split your if/else statements into multiple functions, and do an &= on the parameter you send to EnableNext. You should be calling EnableNext only once.

So, for example:

```
// in CWorkStation::ProcessEvent
bool enableNext = true; // start with true

enableNext &= Condition1(); // of course pick better names than Condition1
enableNext &= Condition2(); // this is just for an example

EnableNext(enableNext);
```

Where Condition1() might be:

```
bool Condition1()
{
    return (IsDlgButtonChecked(IDC_USEDBNAME) 
         && !IsDlgButtonChecked(IDC_MAXDBNAME));
}
```

And so on.

What's happening here is that the enableNext variable starts with true. Then, each &= you do means that if any of the ConditionX() functions returns false, enableNext will end up false. It will only be true at the end if ALL of the conditions are true.

Comment: Looks good. Now I just have to find out exactly what "&=" does.

Comment: ah yes. &= is a logical shortcut operator.

enableNext &= Condition1() is the same as enableNext = enableNext && Condition()

Well, technically, it's enableNext = enableNext & Condition1(), but for bools it is effectively the same thing. See edit to post.

Comment: Small note: One might need to take care that there is no &&= operator, so Condition1() is always called with &=. Works well if the function has no side-effects, but if it changes state you might get something unespected.

Answer (score 1):

That problem can be solved with the concept of listeners.

You can make each of your GUI components have a `isEnabled()` method, which checks its conditions based on some conditions. The `isEnabled()` is called on each GUI component when any action that changes the state of any component is called.

This way you can have the following declarations:

```
bool CheckBoxComponent::isValid() {
   return isNameFilled() && isEmailChecked();
}

bool OkButton::canSend() {
   return checkBoxName->isValid() && isEmailChecked();
}
```

Then, when creating your GUI components you make each of them connect to each other via listener.

This way you have the rules for each component where they belong and you don't have tons of if statements.

Comment: Seems cut out for the `Observer` pattern indeed. Process the event and then use the `notify` method of the object to notify all those `Observers` that are registered for it.

Answer (score 0):

It may help to try to formulate the rules as a state-machine, but if that is practical depends on their nature. In that approach, whenever the user fills out some field in the dialog, or checks a checkbox or whatever, you update the state of your sate-machine accordingly. If you have that, you can use [Boost.Statechart](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/statechart/doc/index.html) to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

In cases like that, I tend to make it as simple as possible by (for example) enabling the button by default, and if any other condition is set (or not), disable it; this limit the different cases in "if" conditions with "else".

Answer (score 0):

Restate your condition as a proper boolean statement, properly indent all conditions and add some comments. IMHO, you shouldn't hide the real checks in single-use methods. If you want to comment code, comment it but don't create methods for that purpose, it only obfuscates things and your conditions don't get any simpler:

```
EnableNext( 
        // condition 1 
        IsDlgButtonChecked(IDC_USEDBNAME) && !IsDlgButtonChecked(IDC_MAXDBNAME)
        // condition 2
    ||  IsDlgButtonChecked(IDC_MAXDBNAME) && CharCount 
        && IsDlgButtonChecked(IDC_USEXMLNAME) && !PrefixName.IsEmpty()
        // condition 3
    ||  IsDlgButtonChecked(IDC_USEXMLNAME) && PrefixName.GetLength() > 1
        // and so on
)
```

This way it becomes immediately obvious that you seem to check the same condition twice `USEXMLNAME && !PrefixName().IsEmpty()`. It is also obvious now, that `EnableNext` is always called.

Comment: good point. one thing I would suggest is to still use the local enableNext and the separate &=, as in my example, but with the conditions inline. this way in the debugger you can tell which condition is causing it to be disabled.

Comment: That can sometimes be useful for debugging. Careful with &= though, it is not a logical operator but a bitwise one.

Answer (score 0):

Though it might be a bit "heavier" of a solution than you'd like, you might want to look at Adobe's [Adam and Eve](http://stlab.adobe.com/group__asl__overview.html) libraries. Eve deals with widget layout, and Adam takes a set of statements about the logic of the widgets and puts them together into a controller that enables and disables widgets based on that logic, as well as handling initialization and putting results into the proper variables (e.g., when the user clicks "Ok").

Comment: Link outdated. New one: http://stlab.adobe.com/group__asl__overview.html

Comment: @Xeverous: Thank you.